# Get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing image's properties returned by UIImagePickerController's didFinishPickingImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working in the simulator right now and when trying to access the attributes of an image returned by UIImagePickerController's didFinishPickingImage, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    NSLog(@"Image size: %@", img.size);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to print object ("%@" format specifier), but size has `CGSize` type which is typedef to plain `struct`. Use

```
NSLog(@"Image size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(img.size));
```

or

```
NSLog(@"Image size: (%f, %f)", img.size.width, img.size.height);
```

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of the [NSStringFromCGSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGSize) function, very cool. Prints size in the form {w,h}

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage.size` is [a structure](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGSize), not an object, so you can't use `%@` in NSLog to log it. Try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"Image size: %.0f %.0f", img.size.width, img.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    NSLog(@"Image size: %f by %f", img.size.width, img.size.height);
}
```